# `const_get': uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I upgraded my Ruby version from 2.5.7 to 2.7.5 and Rails from 5.2.4.4 to 6.1.5.

And I got this error

```
/home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:287:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Web::Shared::CommercialBeyondBannerHelper (NameError)
```

`web/shared/_commercial_beyond_banner_helper.rb`:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Web::Shared
  module CommercialBeyondBannerHelper

    def function
      # something here
    end

  end
end
```

This is full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    81: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    80: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    79: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    78: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    77: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    76: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    75: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    74: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    73: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    72: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    71: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    70: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
    69: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    68: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    67: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    66: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    65: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    64: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    63: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    62: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    61: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    60: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    59: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    58: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    57: from /home/rth/khoi/rails/burpple-on-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    56: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `method_missing'
    55: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:207:in `public_send'
    54: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
    53: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    52: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    51: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    50: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    49: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    48: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    47: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    46: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    45: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    44: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    43: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    42: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    41: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    40: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    39: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    38: from /home/rth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    37: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    36: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    35: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    34: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    33: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
    32: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    31: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
    30: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
    29: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.7.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
28: from /home/rth/khoi/rails/burpple-on-rails/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:266:in `<main>'
    27: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    26: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    25: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in `<main>'
    24: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    23: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    22: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:2:in `<main>'
    21: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:3:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
    20: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
    19: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
    18: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
    17: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/inherited_resources-1.13.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:1:in `<main>'
    16: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/inherited_resources-1.13.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:11:in `<module:InheritedResources>'
    15: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
    14: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
    13: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
    12: from /home/rth/khoi/rails/burpple-on-rails/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `<main>'
    11: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:19:in `inherited'
    10: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:147:in `helper'
     9: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:104:in `modules_for_helpers'
     8: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:169:in `modules_for_helpers'
     7: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:169:in `map!'
     6: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:176:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
     5: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:74:in `constantize'
     4: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `constantize'
     3: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `inject'
     2: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `each'
     1: from /home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:287:in `block in constantize'
/home/rth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.7.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:287:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Web::Shared::CommercialBeyondBannerHelper (NameError)
```

It is still working well in old version!
Can you help me! thanks!

Comment: The underscore at the start of `_commercial_beyond_banner_helper.rb` stands out  as the filename does not match the class name. You could try removing it.

Comment: As of Rails 6, the autoloader [changes to Zeitwerk](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html); have you verified that it's zeitwerk-compliant? (from time to time I've seen issues with declaring as you do in `Web::Shared` style)

Comment: In `zeitwerk` mode that style works 100%. Those issues happened in `classic` mode due to limitations in its technique.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that some code tried to use `Web::Shared::CommercialBeyondBannerHelper` but that module has not been initialized yet and it couldn't be auto-loaded because it couldn't be found.

[`zeitwerk`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html) is the new autoloader in Rails 6 and tries to lazy-load as much as possible.

The link above gives a good explanation for the switch and great tips on how to find potential issues (by running `bin/rails zeitwerk:check`).

As @Arctodus suggests, this is usually as simple as a filename or directory issue.

zeitwerk expects to be able to find constants by directory and filename, with some flexibility.

Your filename starts with an underscore: `web/shared/_commercial_beyond_banner_helper.rb`

zeitwerk expect that only view partials start with an underscore.

If this file is a view partial, it's strange that you're defining a module in it, and even more strange that you're calling that module someplace else.